# Using a strong enum (C++11) of type bool fails for template bool argument, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

```
enum class test : bool { yes=true, no=false };

template< bool ok >
class A {
};

int main(){
A<test::yes> a;
}
```

Why compiling this fails? (g++ 4.7) As C++11 enums are strongly typed so we should be able to use a bool enum as bool parameter for template types?

Comment: You need an explicit cast to convert strongly-typed enums to their [underlying type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type)

Comment: That is exactly what strongly-typed means: the type of `test::yes` is `test`, not `bool`, and the whole point of strongly-typed enums is that there is no implicit conversion between them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strongly typed enums mean that you can only, implicitly, compare and assign values in the same enum class. The solution is to use a non-strongly typed enum example:

```
enum test : bool
{
    yes = true,
    no = false
};
bool x = test::yes; // ok
```

Or as suggested by Tom Knapen: explicitly cast the enum

```
enum class test : bool
{
    yes = true,
    no = false
};
bool x = static_cast<bool>(test::yes); // ok
```

Comment: Doesn't your code reverse the boolean meaning of `test::yes` and `test::no` compared to the original version?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the cast simpler with a template:-

```
enum class Test: bool {
    No = false,
    Yes = true
};

template <typename E>
constexpr auto operator+(E e) noexcept {
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}

template <typename E, std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same<bool, std::underlying_type_t<E>>::value, 
        int
    > = 0
>
constexpr E operator not (E e) noexcept {
    return static_cast<E>(!static_cast<bool>(e));
}

// then 
bool x {+Test::Yes};
```